# Kernel cleanup hangs on Postinst

Tags: apt, kernel

Performing an upgrade tries to remove something from an old kernel, I did uninstall last time - maybe it got stuck last time as well, I had just not bothered on the console, as I was in hurry.

Log from apt:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paketaktualisierung (Upgrade) wird berechnet... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 1 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
1 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Nach dieser Operation werden 153 MB Plattenplatz freigegeben.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j
(Lese Datenbank ... 201432 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Entfernen von linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic (4.4.0-97.120) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-97-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-97-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-97-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-97-generic
```

How can I remove the kernel to stop apt to hang up at this point?

Comment: You might try reinstalling it? `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic`

Comment: @Zanna reinstall does hang up at the same point